# Difference between 'yet' and 'although'

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, conjunctions

Training for a TOEIC exam, I got this question.

[image: yet or although]

Answers `just` and `moreover` are easily discarded.
The choices `yet` and `although` remain.

The correct (expected) answer is the first one.
I'm confused why.

Definitions:

- **although**: *in spite of the fact that; even though*
- **yet**: *1. up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then 2. still; even 3. in spite of that; nevertheless*

According to this [question about the difference between 'but' and 'yet'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471542/difference-between-but-and-yet), *yet* might be used when you have an element of surprise.
Is this true and the case here? Can you give me a definition showing this?

If the question had been:
`_________, SO FAR, very few customers upgraded their accounts.`, I would have picked yet.

What makes the answer *yet* more correct than *although*?
Could the answer *although* be considered valid english (even if a "less" correct answer)?

Comment: Although the new service was expected to be a success, very few customers upgraded their accounts.  Very few customer upgraded their accounts, although the new service was expected to be a success. The new service was expected to be a success; (and) yet very few customers upgraded their accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "yet" expresses a contrast between an implicit expectation and the factual result and signals the latter: "The new services was expected to be a success so customers could have gained some profit by upgrading their accounts. Yet (but/however) they didn't". You could also use "although", but the latter refers to the expectation and not to the result. So you would have to phrase it as: "Although the new service was expected [...], very few customers [...]".

Comment: « expectation and not the result »: that was the key part to help me differentiate them. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! I see your native language is French. In this case "yet" corrsponds to "cependant" and "although" to "bien que".

Comment: You're happy with the semicolon before [yet]?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am mostly happy regardless of linguistics. So I wouldn't "make an elefant out of a mosquito",  as a literally translated German saying goes, out of this detail.

Comment: In spite of << 'DO NOT use the semicolon in the following cases: ... Between complete sentences joined by and, nor, but, or, yet, so (coordinating conjunctions)' >> (from [Saint Michael's College, VT](http://academics.smcvt.edu/writingctr/semicolons.htm)) and << 'When a conjunction (words like and, but and or) is used to merge two independent clauses into one sentence, it is possible to use a semicolon before the conjunction **to outrank any commas in the clause.** (This practice is acceptable, but it is considered outdated these days ....

Comment: However, if you think a semicolon makes your sentence clearer, you can use one.)' >> [[GrammarMonster; bolding mine](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_before_conjunctions.htm)] Here, there is no justification for a semicolon, and I'd mark the 'yet' answer _incorrect_ also. 'However,', including the comma, needs to be included.